# A term to describe a phrase that can be changed without having to know the origin

Tags: phrases

I'm sure I read about this on this website, but I am clueless as to what it was.  An example may be adding 'gate' to the end of scandal titles.  People understand it enough to use it to describe other scandals with out knowing where it started.  I have a vague recollection of the name of this having something to do with *snow???* but please don't quote me on that

Comment: They're  known as _snowclones_.

Comment: Thankyou. I knew I had seen the term on here, but was hard to search for it when I couldn't remember the term

Comment: No problem. Yours is a rare example of a duplicate that can't be expected to be checked for being such. It's closed to keep the site tidy.